# Multiple subscribers to service

Tags: ros, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good evening,

I may have misunderstood the concept of ROS services, but is it possible to have multiple client calling for the same service?

For instance, I have a service running on a server that processes raw images and returns informations about them. Can I have a service that use those informations and another that register the output of server?

If yes, should I create a new node that publish the data, or is it possible to make the service directly speak with the database?

Thank you in advance,
Julien Girard

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235750/multiple-subscribers-to-service/) by [Rhapsodos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27038/rhapsodos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I may have misunderstood the concept of ROS services, but is it possible to have multiple client calling for the same service?

Yes, this is possible. A service-server offers a service, that any node can use. Each client sends some information to the service and gets a corresponding response. See also [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29) for a simple example.

> For instance, I have a service running on a server that processes raw images and returns informations about them. Can I have a service that use those informations and another that register the output of server?

So, if I understand correctly, you want to send some raw images to the service server and get information about them as a response? Yes, this is possible with a service server.
If your server just processes the images it gets from an external non-ROS source and you want to use them in another ROS node, then it would be better to publish them as a topic.

---

Originally posted by [JohnDoe2991](https://answers.ros.org/users/21163/johndoe2991/) with karma: 305 on 2016-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rhapsodos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27038/rhapsodos/) on 2016-06-02**:
Thank you very much for your explanation. Considering that I have nodes that uses differently inputs and outputs of this server, I will publish them on a topic.